# How to use String methods to swap 0's and 1's inside a string

Tags: java

I am currently working on a problem for my high school computer programing course that asks: A string contains only '0' and '1' characters and spaces. Write a method that takes such a string and makes and returns a "negative" string in which all the 0s are replaced with 1s and all the 1s with 0s. Your method must rely only on String's methods and not use any explicit iterations or recursion.

```
public static String negativeBits(String s)
{
    String answer = s.replaceAll("0", "1");
    answer = s.replaceAll("1", "0");
    return answer;
}
```

So I was thinking I can use the replaceAll function to do this, but then realized that the flaw is that it changes everything to 1's first, and then to 0s. I am not sure as to how to change my code so that it swaps the numbers.
Thank You,
Eager Coder

Comment: Seems quite trivial, how would you exchange the value of two variables? By using a third temporary one, the same principle can be applied to your situation.

Comment: To illustrate @Jack's point, when swapping two integers, you might have `int first = 0, second = 1; int tmp = first; first = second; second = tmp;`. You can apply the same thinking with replaceAll();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is like a swap problem. Replace one of them as 2(or any other values) first then change it back:

```
s = s.replaceAll("0", "2");
s = s.replaceAll("1", "0");
s = s.replaceAll("2", "1");
```

Comment: You pretty much copied the comments and spoon fed a student, rather than encouraging him to think.

Comment: Copy the comment? When I write the solution, I didn't even look at the comments. You can check the time I wrote this the time your comment was published.

Comment: Comments were published 4 minutes and 2 minutes before your solution.

Comment: @EricJ. And it was only 1min+ apart. If I would have copied it, I wouldn't write it so quickly. Well, I say it again, I didn't copy from the comments.

Comment: @EricJ. Further more, if I were to use an idea from the comment, I will definitely give credits to whom said it. But from the very beginning I didn't even look at the comments.